# How to save multiple tables related to each other with Prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I'm working on a NestJS project and I have two tables (`TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`), `TABLE_1` schema looks like this:

```
model TABLE 1 {
  id                            String @id @default(uuid())
  secondaryfield                String @unique @map("secondary_field") @db.VarChar(12)
  table_2                       Table_2[]
}
```

And table 2:

```
model TABLE 2 {
  id                           String @id @default(uuid())
  table_1_id                   String @unique @map("secondary_field") @db.VarChar(12)
  table_1                      Table_1 @relation(fields: [table_1_id], references: [id])
}
```

Since there's a FK on my `table_2` that depends on `table_1`, and both of them will be saved at the same time, is there any way that allows Prisma to deal with this and save multiple fields (not only two like the example) with multiple relations between them? I'm using createMany() method as I usually save dozens of those at the same time.

Comment: "deal with this" in what way? Could you clarify what are you trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: My bad, I tought I made it clear enough after mentioning the createMany(), but I just updated my question: I wanna know if there's a way for Prisma to deal with this and save multiple fields with multiple relations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the following:

```
prisma.table2.create({
  data: {
    table1: {
      createMany: {
        data: [
          {
            secondaryfield: 'table1-1',
          },
          {
            secondaryfield: 'table1-2',
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  }
})
```

More info [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes)

Comment: [Nested writes is not possible with `createMany`](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5455), so the second query is wrong. 

If you want to create records in multiple tables at the same time, you have to use `create`. If you are using `createMany`, then you have to handle records from both tables separately.

Comment: I was about to say what @TasinIshmam just said, but thanks anyway! The thing is, I have multiple relations between multiple tables with multiple fields, so as the docs says, createMany might not be an option.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, thanks for the correction, I have updated the answer

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I was looking for, even tough it's been sometime, I'll make sure to test it asap, but I'll publish my own answer, since I found a better way of doing it! Thanks for your help!